# Will the garbage collector collect Go routines that will never continue?

Tags: memory-leaks, go, goroutine

Consider the following code as a simplified example:

```
func printer(c <-chan int) {
    for {
        fmt.Print(<-c)
    }
}

func provide() {
    c := make(chan int)

    go printer(c)

    for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}
```

The function `provide` creates a go routine `printer` that prints the data `provide` generates.

My question is, what happens after `provide` returns and `printer` starts blocking on the empty channel. Will the go routine leak, as there is no further reference to `c` or will the garbage collector catch this case and dispose both the go routine and `c`?

If it is indeed the case that this kind of code causes a memory leak, what strategies can I do to prevent such a memory leak from happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Close the channel. Reading from a closed channel always succeeds, returning a respective zero value. The optional second boolean returned value indicates validity of the first value.

[Receive operator](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator):

> A receive expression used in an assignment or initialization of the form

```
x, ok = <-ch
x, ok := <-ch
var x, ok = <-ch
```

> yields an additional result of type `bool` reporting whether the communication succeeded. The value of `ok` is true if the value received was delivered by a successful send operation to the channel, or false if it is a zero value generated because the channel is closed and empty.

```
func printer(c <-chan int) {
        for {
                v, ok := <-c
                if !ok { // chan closed
                        return
                }

                // v is valid
                fmt.Println(v)
        }
}

func provide() {
        c := make(chan int)

        go printer(c)

        for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
                c <- i
        }
        close(c)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Apparently my "solution" did not really work well.

Comment: using a range clause in the printer goroutine will avoid the ok check -> for v := range c { fmt.Println(v) }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following program to verify that this indeed leaks memory. Please notice that this program eats up your RAM rather quickly; be prepared to kill it.

```
package main

func worker(c <-chan int) {
    var i int

    for {
        i += <-c
    }
}

func wrapper() {
    c := make(chan int)

    go worker(c)

    for i := 0; i < 0xff; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    for {
        wrapper()
    }
}
```

In order to resolve the leak, close a channel that is referenced by the now orphaned go routine. The runtime notices that a Go routine reading from only closed channels will never continue and proceeds to free it. The fixed code looks like this:

```
package main

func worker(c <-chan int) {
    var i int

    for {
        i += <-c
    }
}

func wrapper() {
    c := make(chan int)
    defer close(c) // fix here

    go worker(c)

    for i := 0; i < 0xff; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    for {
        wrapper()
    }
}
```